# Asynchronous download a list of URLs with Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I am a novice in asynchronous programming and `Boost.Asio`. I have a basic question. There is an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/client/async_client.cpp) on `boost.org`. I would like to use it for downloading a list of links. The following is the client code for http asynchronous client.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  try {
    if (argc != 3) {
      ...
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    client c(io_service, argv[1], argv[2]);
    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I see how I can download an URL with this code. However, I couldn't realize how to *asynchronously* (**edit:** simultaneously?) download a list of URLs. Could you help me to change this code for obtaining this purpose?

Comment: Because all of the logic is handled directly in the `client` class, just create multiple instances of the `client` class, one for each of the `URL`s in your list.

Comment: Thank you. However, if I have a lot of links, there is a problem. I can split the original list to smaller chanks and process any chank separately. Then I need to wait until all links of current chank were processed before to process next chank. Is there a way to avoid the efficiency problem?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [Urdl](http://think-async.com/Urdl) HTTP client library by Christopher M. Kohlhoff, the author of Boost.Asio.

This library has a `read_stream` class that allows asynchronous operations. Accrording to [documentation](http://think-async.com/Urdl/doc/html/urdl/reference/core/read_stream.html) it would look like this:

```
#include <urdl/read_stream.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
// run io_service some way

urdl::read_stream in(io_service);
std::ostream& out = std::cout;
char data[1024];

void open_handler(boost::system::error_code const& ec);
void read_handler(boost::system::error_code const& ec, std::size_t length);

in.async_open("http://example.com/path", open_handler);


void open_handler(boost::system::error_code const& ec)
{
  if (!ec)
  {
    in.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), read_handler);
  }
}

void read_handler(boost::system::error_code const& ec, std::size_t length)
{
  if (!ec)
  {
    out.write(data, length);
    in.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), read_handler);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The asynchrony in the sample exists in the fact that all the connections are handled *asynchronously*. This is what enables many downloads to run simultaneously on a single thread (in the code sample from your question, that's the main thread).

So the sample was already asynchronous. Now you are looking for concurrency with your other code :)

--> Just execute the `io_service::run` call on a separate thread (or do your other work on a thread).

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I did not realize id clear. Did you mean, I need something like [this](http://codelever.com/blog/2013/06/18/using-boost-asio-io-service-in-another-thread/)?

Comment: That's one pretty oft-used way yes

Comment: I am afraid I do not catch yet, how it can help.

Comment: @Loom Then I'm afraid you're gonna have to try something. From the code you showed I conclude you have all the relevant bits. You know what threads are, and you know how to use `io_service`.